# Construct the paper model on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am studying Peterson's book of riemannian geometry and he gives me a metric:

$$g = dt^2 + a^2t^2d\theta^2$$

and asks me to identify which are the spaces when I change $a$.

I never expected anything like this before, how can I think about this problem?

Comment: Is the second term $a^{2} t^{2}\, d\theta^{2}$, by chance? :)

Comment: yes! Thank you @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: Here are a couple of hints (in addition to the hint implicit in the title): $dt^{2} + t^{2}\, d\theta^{2}$ is the flat (Euclidean) metric in polar coordinates. The multiplicative factor $a^{2}$ scales the length of each circle $t = \text{constant}$ without changing its "radius" (distance to the origin), and without changing the local isometry class of the metric (away from the origin).

Comment: @Andrew, I will think about it! Thanks

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, what does the book mean by cone? It says that for $a>1$ it is a cone. What does it mean?

Comment: Probably the book meant "for $0 < a < 1$...." (The length of the curve $t = t_{0}$ is $2\pi a^{2} t_{0}$, which must be smaller than $2\pi$ for a circular cone of rotation.) That said, you can make a paper model for the case $1 < a$ by cutting out _two_ paper disks, slitting each along a ray from the center, and attaching _one edge of one slit_ to the "opposing" edge of the other slit, keeping the other two edges free. Now manipulate the model by "opening" the central angle, so that _more_ than $2\pi$ worth of angle comes to the vertex at the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0 < a$, the metric
$$
g = dt^{2} + a^{2} t^{2}\, d\theta^{2},\qquad
0 < t,\quad 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi,
$$
is flat, and represents a cone if $0 < a < 1$, a flat plane if $a = 1$, or a "saddle cone" (non-standard term?) if $1 < a$.
[image: A cone]
[image: A saddle cone]

Each such metric embeds isometrically in Euclidean $3$-space, and the space of isometric embeddings is infinite-dimensional: Pick a smooth, embedded, constant-speed curve $\gamma$ of length $2\pi a$ on the unit sphere, and define
$$
\phi(t, \theta) = t\gamma(\theta).
$$
Since $\phi_{t} = \gamma$ lies on the unit sphere and $\phi_{\theta} = t\gamma'$ is tangent to the sphere and has constant speed $a$, the components of the induced metric are
$$
E = 1,\qquad
F = 0,\qquad
G = t^{2} \|\gamma'\|^{2} = a^{2} t^{2}.
$$

Comment: How did you do the graphics?

Comment: @user66081: [ePiX](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/images/gallery-1.2/index.html), effectively a dialect of C++ that outputs LaTeX picture environments.

Comment: Ok, this is good to know; so I assume you specified the surfaces by a parameterization (rather than just the metric).

Comment: @user66081: Yes, that's right.

Comment: thank you so much!!!!!! Nice pics