# Does this first fundamental form imply a surface of revolution?

Tags: differential-geometry

A surface of revolution has the following first fundamental form
$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    r^2(s)& 0\\
0 &1\end{pmatrix}. $$

But does this first fundamental form imply that the surface is a surface of revolution?

Comment: Implicit in that notation for a surface of revolution is the assumption that $|r'(s)|\le 1$. If $r(s)=s$, we'll get the plane parametrized (as a surface of revolution) by polar coordinates. What if $r(s)=2s$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no. Such a surface could be a cylinder over an arbitrary smooth plane curve, or could admit a one-parameter family of "helical" ambient isometries, see ["Self-sliding" surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070121).

Further, as Ted notes, not every such metric embeds as a surface of rotation (even if, like Ted's ["saddle cone"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893493), the metric embeds isometrically in Euclidean $3$-space).

You might be interested in [*A symplectic look at surfaces of revolution*](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-66685), l'Enseignement Mathématique **49** (2003), 157-172.