# Does any symmetric surface look like a surface of revolution?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, riemann-surfaces

Let $(M^2,g,\boldsymbol{\xi})$ be a two-dimensional Riemannian manifold endowed with a Riemannian metric $g$ (strictly positive signature) and a Killing field $\boldsymbol{\xi}$. Will there be an isometric embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that it is symmetric under rotations about some straight line ?

Comment: Do you assume compactness of the surface? Embedding in what space? What kind of an embedding? (Presumably, isometric?)  What did you try to answer your own question?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks. Yes, isometric embedding in 3 dimensional Euclidean space. I would be interesting in both compact and non-compact cases. I guess the answer is not because there may be Killing fields that act non-trivially, but for the moment I cannot figure out a counterexample.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but close enough to resolve the question in the negative: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370393/does-this-first-fundamental-form-imply-a-surface-of-revolution

Comment: Then there are all kinds of obstructions to the existence of a rotationally symmetric  isometric embedding. Start from the fact that hyperbolic plane has no isometric **immersions** in $E^3$, regardless of symmetry. Flat torus does not admit isometric immersions if you care about compact surfaces.